# Why Can I Not Use CSS To Style Elements Inside InfoWindows?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to change the font-size for the elements within my InfoWindows.
The code for my InfoWindow looks like this:

```
<InfoWindow 
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
          onClose={this.onClose}
        >
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.busy}</h4>
          </div>
</InfoWindow>
```

If I try to use CSS to style elements like h1 and h4 nothing happens, the elements within the info windows don't change :/

```
//inside a CSS file that I import
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Does anyone know a fix? From other posts I understand that the actual InfoWindows are very difficult to edit but I believe that shouldn't be true of their child elements?

Comment: Using the style attribute simply removes my page altogether and only shows a blank screen

Comment: A word of warning about the answer you accepted. It is plain wrong and you probably shouldn't be using it. If that CSS rule doesn't work, it's because you have another one overriding it, or it isn't applied for some reason. There is no reason at all why you could not apply this rule to an `<h1>` element inside an Info Window.

Comment: It puzzles me as well because there definitely is no other CSS rule overriding it unless InfoWindow has default rules for its child elements? I also ensured that the CSS file was being imported, and I am confident it is because all other elements were receiving styling.

Comment: Well that's easy to check... Inspect your `<h1>` element and see what styles are applied. By default, there is no style specific to `<h1>` elements that is applied by the Google Maps stylesheets so providing your own should work without any issue. Can you reproduce this in a stack snippet or external jsfiddle/codesandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For infoWindow, you can override the values of the .gm-style .gm-style-iw as stated [here](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/291#issuecomment-443115389).

You can add something like this in your CSS file to change the styling of your infowindow:

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

You can also use different style elements like this when you call your InfoWindow in your ReactJS code:

```
<InfoWindow>
                 <div>
                 <h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Heading!</h1>
                 <span>This is InfoWindow message!</span>
              </div>
             </InfoWindow>
```

Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-mkwi9t?file=Map.js) where I use [react-google-maps library](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#infowindow).  Make sure to change the value of the **API key** in the *[index.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-simple-map-mkwi9t?file=index.js)* file for the code to run.

Here's also a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/pjdo98r5/) where I changed the infowindow style using CSS in a plain JavaScript code.

Comment: This is prone to failure as these class names, as well as any other class name output by the API are **undocumented**. Do not use this solution. There is absolutely no reason why you could not style an `<h1>` element in an Info Window without using these class names.